# How to initiate face scanning for Apple Photos on Mac Mojave?

Tags: mac, photos

My Apple Photos has 1000+ photos but it only scanned 100+. It says that it will scan when my Mac is charged and when the app is not used. However, it didn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can manually initiate the scanning process?

Comment: There isn’t a way. I asked the same question a while back...

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254567/how-can-i-make-the-face-recognition-process-continue?rq=1 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358860/what-are-the-required-conditions-for-photos-to-start-a-facial-scan?rq=1

Comment: So @dwightk thinks there isn't a way while ankii thinks there are at least two ways?

Comment: @Dr_Hope the questions I linked just list the hit and trials people did. Not an exact answer I'd say.